# Merge selected values from multiple json files into main json file

Tags: json, python-3.x, merge

Having main json file name as main.json with content as below

```json
{
  "expand": "schema,names",
  "startAt": 0,
  "maxResults": 300,
  "total": 2,
  "issues": [
    {
      "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
      "id": "54428",
      "self": "/issue/54428",
      "key": "21075",
      "fields": {
        "summary": "external user id",
        "customfield_11700": "External Id and ceres related API calls",
        "components": [
          {
            "self": "component/10108",
            "id": "10108",
            "name": "PP"
          }
        ],
        "customfield_11701": "API calls",
        "customfield_10311": "Handling the out of index exception"
      }
    },
    {
      "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
      "id": "54413",
      "self": "issue/54413",
      "key": "NEUR-21070",
      "fields": {
        "summary": "button alignment",
        "customfield_11700": "None",
        "components": [
          {
            "self": "component/10108",
            "id": "10108",
            "name": "DP"
          }
        ],
        "customfield_11701": "No",
        "customfield_10311": "Corrected "
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In above json i have to merge values present under issues and update count of total in main.json

I have two jsons named as  1.json and 2.json

1.json

```json
{
  "expand": "schema,names",
  "startAt": 0,
  "maxResults": 300,
  "total": 1,
  "issues": [
    {
      "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
      "id": "50008",
      "self": "/issue/50008",
      "key": "21000",
      "fields": {
        "summary": "external user id",
        "customfield_11700": "External Id and ceres related API calls",
        "components": [
          {
            "self": "component/1010",
            "id": "1010",
            "name": "PP"
          }
        ],
        "customfield_11701": "API calls",
        "customfield_10311": "Handling the out of index exception"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

2.json

```json
{
  "expand": "schema,names",
  "startAt": 0,
  "maxResults": 300,
  "total": 1,
  "issues": [
    {
      "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
      "id": "50008",
      "self": "/issue/50018",
      "key": "21010",
      "fields": {
        "summary": "external user id",
        "customfield_11700": "External Id and ceres related API calls",
        "components": [
          {
            "self": "component/1011",
            "id": "1011",
            "name": "PP"
          }
        ],
        "customfield_11701": "API calls",
        "customfield_10311": "Handling the out of index exception"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Finally after merging values from 'issues' from 1.json and 2.json need to merge in main.json and key 'total' count need to be updated in main.json as below

After merging main.json should look like

```json
{
  "expand": "schema,names",
  "startAt": 0,
  "maxResults": 300,
  "total": 4,
  "issues": [
    {
      "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
      "id": "54428",
      "self": "/issue/54428",
      "key": "21075",
      "fields": {
        "summary": "external user id",
        "customfield_11700": "External Id and ceres related API calls",
        "components": [
          {
            "self": "component/10108",
            "id": "10108",
            "name": "PP"
          }
        ],
        "customfield_11701": "API calls",
        "customfield_10311": "Handling the out of index exception"
      }
    },
    {
      "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
      "id": "54413",
      "self": "issue/54413",
      "key": "NEUR-21070",
      "fields": {
        "summary": "button alignment",
        "customfield_11700": "None",
        "components": [
          {
            "self": "component/10108",
            "id": "10108",
            "name": "DP"
          }
        ],
        "customfield_11701": "No",
        "customfield_10311": "Corrected "
      }
    },
    {
      "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
      "id": "50008",
      "self": "/issue/50008",
      "key": "21000",
      "fields": {
        "summary": "external user id",
        "customfield_11700": "External Id and ceres related API calls",
        "components": [
          {
            "self": "component/1010",
            "id": "1010",
            "name": "PP"
          }
        ],
        "customfield_11701": "API calls",
        "customfield_10311": "Handling the out of index exception"
      }
    },
    {
      "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
      "id": "50008",
      "self": "/issue/50018",
      "key": "21010",
      "fields": {
        "summary": "external user id",
        "customfield_11700": "External Id and ceres related API calls",
        "components": [
          {
            "self": "component/1011",
            "id": "1011",
            "name": "PP"
          }
        ],
        "customfield_11701": "API calls",
        "customfield_10311": "Handling the out of index exception"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

To achieve it used below code. Need help to see main.json in format mentioned above

```
import json

files=['1.json','2.json']
sume = 0
issue = []
for f in files:
    with open(f,'r') as infile:
        data = json.load(infile)
        issue.append(data['issues'])
        datotal = data['total']
        sume  += datotal
with open('main.json', 'w') as output_file:
        json.dump(issue, output_file)
```

Comment: You're never using `sume` again or modifying `main.json`. What do you think you need to do?

Comment: main.json need to be modifed to update "total" count and update "issues". I was trying adding of "total" count using object "sume" not sure if this approach is correct or not